# generate random letter from word in c - my coding seems to not work

Tags: c, random

My output is blank. I'm trying to get a random letter from a user entered word. Any help?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>

int main (void) {

srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));
int i = 0;

char char1[31];

printf("Enter a word with 30 or fewer characters (no spaces):\n ");
scanf("%c", &char1[51]);

for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    int num = 
    printf("Your random character is: %c", char1[rand() % (sizeof char1)]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, `scanf("%c", &char1[51]);` ==> `scanf("%30s", char1);` And unless you want to roll the dice on garbage values and terminators, etc, the modulus in your random pick should be the string length, not the buffer size.

Comment: so it shouldn't be (sizeof char1)? How should I change it to string length? What would that look like? I'm new to c and i'm just getting familiar with the terms

Comment: Typing random stuff in an attempt to learn C by trial & error doesn't work. You have to study a beginner-level book, there is no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%c", &char1[51]);` is undefined behavior as `char1` only have 31 bytes allocated.  The other issue is that you use `sizeof()` which would return 31 even if you only read in, say, 3 characters.  In this case there would be a  `1 - 3/30 = 90%` chance of returning uninitiated data, and this may very well be `\0`  which would not print anything.  Use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()` to get length of the string you just read into `char1`.

Here is a minimal working program (scanf ensures at least 1 byte is read, otherwise you need to check for that special case):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LEN 30
#define str(i) xstr(i)
#define xstr(i) #i

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Enter a word with %d or fewer characters (no spaces): ", LEN);

    char char1[LEN + 1];
    scanf("%" str(LEN) "s", char1);

    printf("Your random character is: %c\n",
        char1[rand() % strlen(char1)]);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Enter a word with 30 or fewer characters (no spaces): abc
Your random character is: a
Enter a word with 30 or fewer characters (no spaces): abc
Your random character is: c
```

Comment: Thank you, i did fix that. However, I'm still not getting a random letter for my output. Any ideas?

Comment: If that answered your question make sure you mark the question answered (click the check mark) so we know you are all set.

Comment: This is way too advanced. The OP doesn't even know how to use arrays and strings yet and then you post an answer using stringification macros and variable format strings...

Comment: @Lundin You are right.  How would I teach op in an easier manner not use hard-code magic values and ensure that scanf is used safely?  I could introduce fread but then I would also need to introduce stdin which is foreign too,